# DRYing out implementation of ICloneable in several classes

Tags: c#, clone, dry, abstraction, deep-copy

I have several different classes that I want to be cloneable:  `GenericRow`, `GenericRows`, `ParticularRow`, and `ParticularRows`.  There is the following class hierarchy:  `GenericRow` is the parent of `ParticularRow`, and `GenericRows` is the parent of `ParticularRows`.  Each class implements `ICloneable` because I want to be able to create deep copies of instances of each.  I find myself writing the exact same code for `Clone()` in each class:

```
object ICloneable.Clone()
{
    object clone;

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Serialize this object
        formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
        stream.Position = 0;

        // Deserialize to another object
        clone = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }

    return clone;
}
```

I then provide a convenience wrapper method, for example in `GenericRows`:

```
public GenericRows Clone()
{
    return (GenericRows)((ICloneable)this).Clone();
}
```

I am fine with the convenience wrapper methods looking about the same in each class because it's very little code and it *does* differ from class to class by return type, cast, etc.  However, `ICloneable.Clone()` is *identical* in all four classes.  Can I abstract this somehow so it is only defined in one place?  My concern was that if I made some utility class/`object` extension method, it would not correctly make a deep copy of the particular instance I want copied.  Is this a good idea anyway?

Answer (score 2):

heading into a meeting so only have time to throw some code at you.

```
public static class Clone
{
    public static T DeepCopyViaBinarySerialization<T>(T record)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, record);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

from within the Clone method:

```
Clone()
{
  Clone.DeepCopyViaBinarySerialization(this);
}
```

Comment: Add a `this` to the `T record` parameter declaration and you don't even need a Clone method in each class (i.e. turn DeepCopyViaBinarySerialization into an extension method).

Comment: link for argument against ICloneable: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/03/125427.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Implementing ICloneable is not a good idea (see Framework Design Guidelines).

Implementing a Clone method with a BinaryFormatter is.... interesting.

I'd actually recommend to write individual Clone methods for each class, e.g.

```
public Class1 Clone()
{
    var clone = new Class1();
    clone.ImmutableProperty = this.ImmutableProperty;
    clone.MutableProperty = this.MutableProperty.Clone();
    return clone;
}
```

Yes, you repeat yourself a lot with this, but it's still the best solution IMHO.

Comment: Lol @ 'interesting'.  That's how deep copies were made in the code I was given, and I never bothered to change it.